# On Linux CentOS 7 OS how schedule jobs to run drush to re-index solr, run cron and clear cache for drupal 7 sites

Tags: drupal-7, centos7, drush

HI a newbie to server management... We need to automate hourly script to run drush to re-index solr, run cron and clear cache on multiple servers. I'm sure there has to be .bat file or something?

Answer (score 0):

At first: You have no '.bat' files in any unix system (but ofcourse you can write scripts named `something.bat`, but nothing special happens ;-)).

You need to have drush installed somewhere in your sytem. I use to install it in `/usr/local/share/drush` and put a link from `/usr/local/share/drush/drush`to `/usr/local/bin/drush`. Then run `crontab -e` to edit the schedule. An editor is launched inside your console window. If it shows an empty window or the file contains only lines starting with "#", then put

```
MAILTO=your.mail@example.com
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:$HOME/bin

@daily    drush @live -q -y cron > /dev/null
```

In this case `drush cron` is executed daily for a drupal installation with a site-alias `@live`. The output is sent to `/dev/null`, so that I do not get any error messages.

PS: Get familiar with the `cron` systems and the `crontab` command as well as shell scripting. They are unix' standard tools and are needed for those kind of tasks.
PS2: You also want to know the concept of drush site-aliases. Run `drush topic docs-aliases` to learn more about it.

Comment: Thanks for your help...Yes I know there is no .bat :) but being a windows guy I knew there had to be something on a unix system that is its equivalent.